# Xamarin iOS - What is the correct NetworkReachability Schedule RunLoop

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I was using this code with NetworkReachability class to determine if the network connection has changed.

```
remoteHostReachability = new NetworkReachability(HostName);
reachable = remoteHostReachability.TryGetFlags(out flags);
remoteHostReachability.SetNotification(OnChange);
remoteHostReachability.Schedule(CFRunLoop.Current, CFRunLoop.ModeDefault);
```

NetworkReachability stopped to send notifications (OnChange wasn't called anymore) after certain iOS and/or Xamarin update - can't pin point what that was exactly, since I didn't know it wasn't working for long time.

Now I figured out that scheduling those notifications using CFRunLoop.Main instead of CFRunLoop.Current does the trick, but I don't know if I should be concerned about putting this into main runloop.

Are there any drawbacks, or is it safe to use main runloop for those notifications?

Comment: Use [Reachability](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/ios/network/reachability/detect_if_network_is_available) instead. `Reachability.ReachabilityChanged += (sender,e1) => { //handle stuff };`

Comment: The code I pasted is taken from  that Reachability class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone came upon this thread and wondered how I solved the problem - I ditched the Reachability class, and used Connectivity from Xamarin.Essentials instead.